# Speedup find command

Tags: unix, find, runtime, csh, xargs

I am getting file count and find size using same find command but currently running find twice as shown below. How to perform both operations in one line and eliminate one find?

```
file_cnt[$i]=$(find $dir_name -type f -ctime +$ctime1 -ctime -$ctime2 | wc -l)
file_size[$i]=$(find $dir_name -type f -ctime +$ctime1 -ctime -$ctime2 | xargs --no-run-if-empty --max-procs=2 du -s | awk '{sum += $1} ; END {printf "%.2f", sum/1024**2}')
```

Answer (score 0):

try something like this

```
read "file_cnt[$i]" "file_size[$i]" << EOF
$(find $dir_name -type f -ctime +$ctime1 -ctime -$ctime2 | xargs --no-run-if-empty --max-procs=2 du -s | awk '{count++;sum += $1} ; END {printf "%d %.2f", count, sum/1024**2}')
EOF
```

Comment: I tried this and gives an error shown below :     read "file_cnt[$i]" "file_size[$i]" << EOF $(find $dir_name -type f -ctime +$ctime1 -ctime -$ctime2 | xargs --no-run-if-empty --max-procs=2 du -s | awk '{count++;sum += $1} ; END {printf "%d %.2f", count, sum/1024**2}') EOF
 read: 6949: invalid variable name
 read: 0: invalid variable name
 read: 0: invalid variable name
 read: 0: invalid variable name
 read: 0: invalid variable name
 read: 0: invalid variable name
 read: 0: invalid variable name

Comment: Also how is the word count wc-l getting captured in the above line into file_cnt[$i] where "i" loops say from 1 to 10

Comment: @Rancho Please show a minimal complete example, i.e. a complete script including a loop and your original code, which can reproduce error messages like in your comment.
The `wc -l` is replaced by counting the lines in the `awk` script. `awk` prints the line count and the sum of the file sizes, `read` should read these two values into two variables.
I just noticed the tag `csh`. Which shell do you use? `csh`? I successfully tried my script snippet with `bash` using a modified find command.

Comment: @Rancho Clarification for my previous comment: 
Your minimal example should work with your two code lines and produce error messages when you replace them with my code.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest to use `find` to return the file sizes and awk to do the sum and the file count:

```
$ find $dir_name -type f -ctime +$ctime1 -ctime -$ctime2 -printf "%s\n" | awk '{s+=$1}{print NR,s}'
```